# Access navigator from within custom IconItemRenderer in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a class in Flex that crates a custom IconItemRenderer by extending the IconItemRenderer base class. I'm using this custom item within a list and listen to mouse press. Depending on the location of the mouse press, I have different options. One of which is to navigate to a different view. I know how to use the change listener of the list to push to a new view but don't want to implement it. The idea for the mouse click is that depending on the location, I can remove elements from the list or open up the current element.

For the life of me I cannot find a method to navigate to a new view from within the IconItemRenderer. This is the code I'm using, both the class and the list where I implement it.

> ```
> package components  
> {  
> import spark.components.Button;  
> import spark.components.IconItemRenderer;  
> import spark.utils.MultiDPIBitmapSource;
>
> public class DeleteItemRenderer extends IconItemRenderer
> {
>     private var btn:Button;
>     private var xIcon:MultiDPIBitmapSource;
>
>     public function DeleteItemRenderer()
>     {
>         super();
>         super.iconWidth = super.iconHeight = 40;
>         super.labelField = 'title';
>         super.decorator = "assets/delete.png";
>     }
>
>     override public function set data(value:Object):void{
>         super.data = value;
>     }
>
>     override protected function layoutContents(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void{
>         setElementPosition(decoratorDisplay, unscaledWidth-40, 5);
>         setElementSize(decoratorDisplay, 40, 40);
>     }
>
>     override protected function measure():void{
>         measuredHeight = 50;
>     }
>
>     override protected function drawBackground(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void{
>         graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
>         graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
>         graphics.endFill();         
>         decoratorDisplay.smooth = true; 
>         graphics.lineStyle(1,0xcccccc,1);
>         graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
>         graphics.endFill();
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

List

```
<s:List id="survey_list" visible="true" width="98%"  height="70%" contentBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" horizontalCenter="0">            
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <components:DeleteItemRenderer width="99.9%" height="98%" verticalAlign="top" click="detectActionPress();">
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import spark.components.ViewNavigator;
                        import spark.components.View;
                        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
                        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
                        import mx.core.UIComponent;
                        import spark.components.List;

                        private var application:UIComponent = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as UIComponent;
                        private var pressOpen:Number = application.width - 40;
                        //private var _navigator:ViewNavigator = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.navigation; //navigation is not defined uhhhh why????

                        private function detectActionPress():void{
                            var localX:Number = this.mouseX;
                            if(localX <= pressOpen){
                                engangeElement();
                            }
                            else{
                                deleteElement();
                            }
                        }

                        private function deleteElement():void{
                            var parentList:List = owner as List;
                            parentList.dataProvider.removeItemAt(parentList.dataProvider.getItemIndex(data));                               
                            trace('element removed');
                        }

                        private function engangeElement():void{
                            var parentList:List = owner as List;

                            var _test:ViewNavigator = this.parentDocument as ViewNavigator;

                            //this.parentApplication.navigator.pushView(views.UnfinishedSurvey, parentList.selectedItem.shortcode)
                            _test.pushView(views.UnfinishedSurvey, parentList.selectedItem.shortcode);
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
            </components:DeleteItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>       
</s:List>
```

Any ideas how I could push a new view from `engageElement();`
Why don't I have access to the navigator?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component Generally; dispatch a bubbling event from the itemRenderer and access the navigator in the event handler.  Alternatively you could use a class that has an instance to the navigator and inject that into your renderer using some type of dependency injenction (DI) framework.  Robotlegs and Swiz are two frameworks that support DI

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Had some issues following your tutorial (had to create the custom class but managed to do it and it works just perfect). Could you please add you comment as an answer so I can validate it? It's a very nice article and I believe others might use it as well. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  The tutorial is intended to overview the approaches without going deep into a code dive.  I wrote the post so I wouldn't have to explain it in formal answers anymore. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally; I would recommend dispatching an event from inside the itemRenderer.  Be sure that the event bubbles.

You can listen to the event on a class which is a hierarchical parent of the itemRenderer / List.

In the event handler you can access the navigator.

I wrote about the [approaches here](http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component); which may provide more details.

There are alternate ways to do this.  You could use a class that has an instance to the navigator and inject that into your renderer using some type of dependency injenction (DI) framework. Robotlegs and Swiz are two ActionScript based frameworks that support this.